# QGIS Plugin installed but reported as invalid

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ordnance-survey, os-mastermap

I'm just discovering QGIS so please excuse my ignorance! I have QGIS 2.4.0 installed, and am trying to install Ordnance Survey Mastermap data. I have installed the OS2OGR translator to handle the decompression of the .GZ files, but the plugin manager reports the plugin is "broken - missing metadata file." I have checked the plugin folder, and the metadata file is there - what am I missing?

Comment: Did you download and install this from the QGIS interface (_Plugins_ > _Manage and Install Plugins..._ >? The plugin is called "Ordnance Survey Translator", this may have been renamed from OS2OGR. I have just downloaded and tested this and it loads up fine.

Comment: Unfortunately due to "Security" protocols at work, the Plugin interface doesn't work, and IT won't release details of the Proxy Server, so I manually downloaded and added the plugin as detailed in other similar questions on the site.

Answer (score 5):

You can manually download your **Ordnance Survey Translator** plugin from the [repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) and extract the folder to the following directory:

```
C:\Users\(your user name)\.qgis2\python\plugins\
```

Restart QGIS and from the toolbar, go to *Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins...*

Your plugin should be listed, check the box next to the plugin name to enable it.

Comment: Make sure to obey the folder structure. It might be possible that you extracted the plugin as a folder named `C:\Users\yourname\.qgis2\python\plugins\os2ogr\os2ogr` which is one folder too much.

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ, very good point and an easy mistake to make (happened to me a couple of times!)

Answer (score 3):

@AndreJ:s comment on another answer solved the issue for me, thought it would be good to add it as a possible answer. If not, please let me know.

Make sure to obey the folder structure. It might be possible that you extracted the plugin as a folder named

```
C:\Users\yourname\.qgis2\python\plugins\my_plugin\my_plugin
```

which is one folder too much.